# italic, bold and underlined font on iPhone

Tags: iphone, fonts

How do you set a font to be both bold and italic.  There is a boldSystemFontOfSize and italicSystemFoneOfSize, but I can't see the way to set a font to be both italic and bold.

As a second question, is there a way to set an underline on a font, or do you simply draw a line under text.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You have to actually ask for the bold, italic version of a font. For example:

```
UIFont *myFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-BoldOblique" size:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
```

To get a list of everything available on the iPhone, put this little snippet in your `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` delegate method and look at the log output:

```
for (NSString *family in [UIFont familyNames]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:family]);
}
```

Note: Some font names say "oblique" - this is the same as italic.

I can't see a built-in way of doing underlines - you may have to draw the line yourself.

Comment: Excellent little snippet to find all the font names.. :-)

Comment: Oblique and Italic are ***not*** the same. [Oblique is merely the face slanted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblique_type). It is not really a style but rather a transformation/distortion. Italic is a style that is designed: notice the difference between Times New Roman and Times New Roman Italic (the italic is not just slanted). Most sans-serif fonts do not have italics (just obliques), but a few do, and they are noticeably different than their non-italic kin.

Comment: Great. Is there an online reference for the fonts and combinations, other than reverting to log output?

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote a blog post about the restrictions of the UIFont API and how to solve it.
You can see it at http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/07/26/uifont-from-a-css-definition/

With the code I provide there, you can get your desired system UIFont as easy as:

`UIFont *myFont = [FontResolver fontWithDescription:@"font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;"];`