# UITextField make text bold?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Quick question, does anyone know how to programatically make the text in the textField **bold** or *italic*?

```
   @property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *textField_TOP_01;

   [textField_TOP_01 setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
   [textField_TOP_01 setText:@"This text is bold"];
```

Much appreciated

Gary

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can use the following methods to get a bold or italic system font;

```
UIFont* boldFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
UIFont* italicFont = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
```

Then simply set the font that the text field uses;

```
[textField_TOP_01 setFont:boldFont];
```

If you want to see more about fonts with the iPhone, you can see a nice screen shot of all of the available fonts here: https://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/02/understanding-uifont/ or you can read about the class which shows you how you can also pull out the 'buttonFontSize' and 'labelFontSize' etc here; https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont

Comment: how to mix between bold and italics how to save the text with this format in txt file

Comment: Depending on what you're after... 1. If you would like something read-only then you could use a UIWebView to display HTML to the user. (http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/display-rich-text-using-a-uiwebview). This wouldn't allow for edits though. 2. If you need a 'Pages' like editable view, then I believe that the OmniGroup libraries provide an editable text area which supports formatting. I've never used it however, and I can't find any documentation easily on github. https://github.com/omnigroup/OmniGroup

Answer (score 9):

Attributes like bold and italic can be set by using the appropriate font. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384181/italic-bold-and-underlined-font-on-iphone/1384206#1384206) for more details.

```
UIFont * font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold"
                                size:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
[textField setFont:font];
```

Alternatively, if you are just looking to create bold and italic versions of the standard iPhone system font, you can use the [boldSystemFontOfSize:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIFont/boldSystemFontOfSize:) or [italicSystemFontOfSize:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIFont/italicSystemFontOfSize:) methods.

Answer (score 5):

If normal font is like,

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"Gill Sans" size:16]]
```

I can make it bold by modifying the line as,

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans-Bold" size:16]]
```

Comment: Perfect! This allowed me to use "Light" font which is all about iOS7 haha!

Answer (score 1):

In swift 3.0 
Suppose your UITextField variable name is textField.

```
textField.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Medium", size: 17)// for medium

name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold" // for bold
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a property called UIFont

`@property(nonatomic, retain) UIFont *font`

For creating a UIFont with a bold, I think you can use:

`+ (UIFont *)fontWithName:(NSString *)fontName size:(CGFloat)fontSize`

`UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:[UIFont systemFontSize]];`