# How to create a font with +fontWithName:size: and specify both the font family name and the specific style information for the font?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uifont

The docs say:

```
+ (UIFont *)fontWithName:(NSString *)fontName size:(CGFloat)fontSize
```

> The fully specified name of the font. This name incorporates both the
>   font family name and the specific style information for the font.

The examples I find only specify a font name. But I want to specify other attributes as well such as medium font weight etc. How is this encoded into the name?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1384206/204826) for naming scheme. Full font list (with names) can be found [here](http://iosfonts.com/).

Example:

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:15.0];
```

---

**Update**

iOS 8.2 added [this method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFont_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIFont/systemFontOfSize:weight:) for fetching system fonts of different weights.

Example:

```
[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0 weight:UIFontWeightBold];
```