# Can't set custom Font in UILabel (iPad app)

Tags: ios, ipad, fonts, custom-font

I load view from bundle and try to set custom font for label in it, but nothing changes.
Outlets for this view and labels are in file's owner.
Here's my code:

```
    self.rikView = (RIKMainToolbar*)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RIKMainToolbarPort" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"PFDinTextCondPro-Medium.ttf" size:46];
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPD: I use this font in iPhone app, but there it's using for label in ViewController and sets in viewDidLoad function. And it works. So, I consider that problem is in loadWithNibName or in iPad.

Solved, thanks to @voromax. The problem was that labels' outlets belonged to file's owner. I've replace it with class and everything works)

Comment: possible dupe - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application

Comment: What if you log the value of this expression `[UIFont fontWithName:@"PFDinTextCondPro-Medium.ttf" size:46];`?

Comment: @voromax Font log: <UICFFont: 0x5d99ad0> font-family: "PF Din Text Cond Pro"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 46px

Comment: @Katerina Korovkina Next we need to be sure this is exact UILabel we mutating. Try to change some other property, text, textColor. If you can't see changes, check binding

Comment: Which method are you doing this in?

Comment: @voromax can't change text too.

Comment: @AshleyMills custom initWithFrame for my class

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I follow your code exactly, but assuming you're making the label.font assignment in initWithFrame of `RIKMainToolbarPort`, try moving it to the `awakeFromNib` method.

Comment: OK, can you please show some more code, including the methods it is called from?

Answer (score 1):

Open the FontBook application, and select "view font info". Copy the post-script-name of your desired font, and use that in your Obj-C code

Comment: That doesn't help. I use right name, I've checked in program. There's font with such name, don't know, why it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the correct font name.
You seem to be using the font file's name, NOT the font name.
For example, in my current app I have the file Opal_1.ttf. However, I use "Opal" as the font name.

Check the example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1384206/855738

Comment: The NSLog from the comment above shows the font is being loaded properly.

Comment: 1. These strings work in the other project 2. I've checked font name and font family in my app with NSLog