# How to center text in UILabel with different fonts

Tags: ios, uilabel, uifont

[image]

I use four fonts in the picture.It seems that different font has different vertical alignment in UILabel.

But I want to **center in vertical or align top** the text with different fonts in UILabel.

The labels is in fixed size.And I should not to change it in my program.

Any one can help me?

Comment: Use textalignment property for UILabel to center align but to make the text top align you need to set edgeinset for UILabel.

Comment: There is no vertical alignment support in UILabel. There are some workarounds - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054558/vertically-align-text-within-a-uilabel.

Answer (score 2):

Make use of the following code for center alignment.

```
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

This **[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054558/vertically-align-text-within-a-uilabel)** answers your question in detail.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.But had you read my question carefully ?

Answer (score 0):

For text alignment you can set as:

```
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

For changing the font use this,

```
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:YOUR_FONT size:SIZE];
```

Answer (score 0):

`yourLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"TrebuchetMS-Bold" size:18];` // to set font style

You can get a list of the available fonts [here](http://iosfonts.com/).

For setting italics and bold, you can go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384181/italic-bold-and-underlined-font-on-iphone).

`yourLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;` // to set alignment to center

There is no direct or already-defined method to align text vertically, but you can find a cross-solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054558/vertically-align-text-within-a-uilabel).

Hope I helped.